# Does anyone know how to use ggplot() to redraw a ggplot2 example given in Quick-R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Does anyone know how to use ggplot() to redraw a ggplot2 example given in Quick-R. The example link is http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/ggplot2.html

I want to redraw the second (or fifth) graph on that webpage by using ggplot(), rather than qplot(). Especially, how to realize the same plot structure (3 by 3 plot, the same label, organizations...)

Specifically, the example is,

```
# ggplot2 examples
library(ggplot2) 

# create factors with value labels 
mtcars$gear <- factor(mtcars$gear,levels=c(3,4,5),
                      labels=c("3gears","4gears","5gears")) 
mtcars$am <- factor(mtcars$am,levels=c(0,1),
                    labels=c("Automatic","Manual")) 
mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl,levels=c(4,6,8),
                     labels=c("4cyl","6cyl","8cyl")) 

# Scatterplot of mpg vs. hp for each combination of gears and cylinders
# in each facet, transmittion type is represented by shape and color
qplot(hp, mpg, data=mtcars, shape=am, color=am, 
      facets=gear~cyl, size=I(3),
      xlab="Horsepower", ylab="Miles per Gallon")
```

How to draw the same picture without change the data.frame structure? That is, only make changes starting from the qplot() code by using ggplot().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a way to reproduce the plot with `ggplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(aes(x=hp, y=mpg, shape=as.factor(am), color=as.factor(am)), data=mtcars)+ 
  facet_grid(gear~cyl) +
  geom_point(size=I(3)) +
  xlab("Horsepower") +
  ylab("Miles per Gallon")
```

[image]

Note that I replaced `am` with `as.factor(am)` since a continuous value cannot be mapped to a `shape` scale. If you want to change the legend title to `am`, like in the original plot, you have to add the following command to the plot:

```
guides(shape = guide_legend(title="am"),
       color = guide_legend(title="am"))
```